# WordPress ReWrite Rules Username Base

Tags: php, regex, wordpress, url-rewriting

I'm trying to create a rewrite rule that would let me catch usernames like

`mydomain.com/{username}`

By using a rule sort of like:

```
'([a-zA-Z0-9\._-]+)/?$' => 'index.php?pagename=profile&username=$matches[1]'
```

However, this would impact all page queries. For example, I still want mydomain.com/about to return the About page, not a username.

Is there anyway I can use the [Rewrite API](https://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_rule) to insert this rule only if the match is an existing username?

Comment: Is this using `MOD_REWRITE` in the .htaccess file?

Comment: I'm using a the Rewrite API (add_rewrite_rule): https://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_rule